# Cout quotation marks don't seem to work (C++)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, integer;
    cout << "Please input an integer ";
    cin >> integer;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1)
        cout << "" << i << " x " << integer << " = " << i * integer;
    cout << endl;
}
```

I am trying to make it display the input integer as eg.

`1 x 4 = 4, 2 x 4 = 8`

Instead I get

`1 x 4 = 42 x 4 = 83`

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you missing a new line, space, or comma? `""` indeed prints exactly nothing as it should.

Comment: It runs the line following the ending paranthesis, and the endl. Add  `{line 1; line 2}` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's no separation between one iteration and the next.  So we print `1 x 4 = 4` immediately followed by `2 x 4 = 8`, giving `1 x 4 = 42 x 4 = 8`.  We need to print some sort of separator; the most usual is to print each entry as a line, ending with a newline character:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int integer;
    std::cout << "Please input an integer ";
    std::cin >> integer;
    if (!std::cin) {
        // read error
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1;  i <= 10;  ++i) {
        //                                                         
        std::cout << i << " ✕ " << integer << " = " << i * integer << '\n';
        //                                                         
    }
}
```

Note that I removed the `<< ""`, as that achieves nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

you have to combine `<< endl` with `cout` . because `for` repeat the line below. like this :

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1) 
      cout << i << " x " << integer << " = " << i * integer << endl;
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, that `cout << "" <<` outputs nothing, and is therefore useless altogether.

Comment: A plain newline (`'\n'`) is probably more appropriate than unnecessarily flushing the stream every line.

Answer (score 0):

U have missed one endl; at the end of cout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, integer;
    cout << "Please input an integer ";
    cin >> integer;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1)
        cout << "" << i << " x " << integer << " = " << i * integer << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, that `cout << "" <<` outputs nothing, and is therefore useless altogether.

Comment: A plain newline (`'\n'`) is probably more appropriate than unnecessarily flushing the stream every line.

Answer (score 0):

To run the if statement always enclose the following statement by curly braces {}.

```
In your case for (i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1)
        {cout << "" << i << " x " << integer << " = " << i * integer << endl;
    cout << endl;}
```

Comment: A plain newline (`'\n'`) is probably more appropriate than unnecessarily flushing the stream every line.

Comment: Definitely. Also there's no need for another cout << endl at the end, a "\n\n" would work fine.